# Can I delete /Library/SystemMigration

Tags: macos

Can I delete /Library/SystemMigration after my upgrade to 10.11. I think, there is nothing, that I want to save.

Answer (score 19):

You can delete this folder.

This directory is a backup of shared caches (relevant to application launches) of the old system.

I saved ~ 600 MB from this.

Comment: I removed my 1.1GB folder with no adverse side effects.

Comment: What steps did you take to "delete" the folder? Was it protected by SIP? Did you disable SIP and then delete it?

Comment: I would like to know how you deleted it as well. I am unable to delete the folder as "Items are in use". I can't even use "sudo rm -rf" to remove the folder, as it just results in a "Permission Denied" error.

Comment: @ajkblue Just deleted it on my Retina 13". Boot into Recovery Mode, disable SIP from the terminal with csrutil disable, reboot, delete folder, and then renable SIP.

Comment: Do you have any reference that could back up your statement about being able to delete this folder? The fact that "the item is in use" sounds like a warning to me…

Comment: @ajkblue I was able to directly `sudo rm -rf` though. No extra message for me.

Comment: On OS X 10.11.4 I just deleted this from the Finder. It simply asked for an administrator's password. I was also able to empty the Trash afterwards. Just saved about 1 GB.

Answer (score 0):

SIP - Enabled
I was able to delete the contents of /Library/SystemMigration/History with enabled SIP by first changing the permissions (CMD-I) and then just removing the folder (~600MB) inside the History folder.
OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score -4):

Don't delete this folder! It's doing something important, because when I tried to delete it I saw a message that the files and folders are in use.

Comment: This folder does nothing useful, and deleting it won't hurt your Mac.