# Can I safely remove the QuarantineRoot folder?

Tags: macos, migration, sip

in El Capitan there is a nice folder called QuarantineRoot ([the Ars review on this matter](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/#h2)) that contains stuff that was in `/usr` in Yosemite but had to be moved (because `/usr`is now protected by SIP).

```
/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-(some UUID)/QuarantineRoot/
```

Can I safely delete it?  I sorted the symlinks to `texbin` that are there, reinstalled [Prey](https://preyproject.com/) etc... is there any risk of a snafu later on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I delete /Library/SystemMigration](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208381/can-i-delete-library-systemmigration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see to have posted a duplicate of [Can I delete /Library/SystemMigration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208381/can-i-delete-library-systemmigration), so I consider this question closed.